# Edit text with round corner and shadow

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to achieve the effect which is shown in this following image:

[image]

In this image there is an edittext with round corner and internal shadow at top. I tried a lot but not success in getting shadow inside edittext.

I searched on this topic but all examples show shadow outside edittext border. I have no idea how can I achieve this.

The button and background image is already done, The only thing which is left is edittext shadow. If someone has already done this or know how to do this please share with me. Any help whould be appreciated.

Comment: create a desired image and set it as a background of Edittext (9 patch image will be preferable)

Comment: I want to do this programmatically if it possible.

Comment: so now you just want give a shadow to that `Editext` right ?

Comment: `android:shadowColor ="#0f0f0f"
    android:shadowRadius="1.6"
    android:shadowDx="1.5"
    android:shadowDy="1.3"`

Answer (score 6):

Got like this

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <gradient
            android:centerY="0.2"
            android:startColor="#FFBDBDBD"
            android:centerColor="#65FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"
            android:angle="270"
            />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#C3C3C3" />
        <corners
            android:radius="25dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just create an xml file in your **drawable** folder name as **round_corner.xml**.And add this following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <corners
        android:radius="3dp"
       />
    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/white"/>

</shape>
```

At Last you add this xml in **background** property of your **Edittext** as follows:-

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
  />
```

Done..Definitely it works..

Comment: When you have radius you already handle bottomLeft, bottomRight, topLeft and topRight. So you can remove those.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Create rounded_edittext.xml file in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="15dp">
 <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
     android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>

  <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#FF0000" />  
</shape>
```

2.) Put below code in styles.xml file placed in values folder

```
<style name="largeEdittextText">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Large.Inverse</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFB90F</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

3.) Apply both on edittext in layout file

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/userName"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:hint="@string/login_userHint"
android:text="admin"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textAppearance="@style/largeEdittextText"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext">
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make the ***border*** of EditText Round and curve, then just paste this code in Drawable/mystyle.xml (create this xml file) .

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:thickness="0dp"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#c8c8c8"/>
   <corners android:radius="11dp" />
</shape>
```

**Now** in your EditText link this file as

```
 android:background="@+drawable/mystyle"
```